# Can you shoot and use upgrades on the reboot token if you arrived there without rebooting?

Tags: robo-rally-2016

Page 15 of the rules says

> You can be shot or pushed by an active robot while on a reboot token, but you cannot shoot robots. You also may not use upgrades.

This seems like it is supposed to apply to robots rebooting, as that makes narrative sense.  Should robots that simply move onto that space without rebooting be allowed to shoot and upgrade?

Comment: I'm finding myself uncertain what to do. I feel the rules are written poorly and the intent is as user aslum called it, but the strict reading does essentially imply what @Samthere, so both are right or neither are wrong.

Answer (score 2):

**No.**

As you mention, the rules don't allow it. They take effect based on the robot being on the reboot token, not based on how it got there. Regardless, it would be easy and reasonable to house rule.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**

The new edition of Robo Rally is riddled with typos and misprints (Virus cards being the biggest one) and poorly worded rules. Rebooting robots can not shoot or use upgrades. By a strict interpretation of the rules (as @Samethere suggests) if two robots die in the first register, the first robot to die would suddenly be able to shoot and use upgrades since they were pushed off the reboot spot by the second dead robot. Similarly you are not prevented from shooting or using upgrades by moving onto the reboot spot; in fact, the reboot spot does not affect your ability to shoot, it's your status as a rebooted robot.